# How to fake Rails session that verifies session ID, IP address and http client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, session

I'm rather new with Rails and I decided to bust my own authentication system that checks for 3 variable constants: IP address, Rails session ID and HTTP client. The way I am getting those are:

```
ip_address = request.env['action_dispatch.remote_ip'].to_s
session_id = request.env['action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie']['session_id'].to_s
http_client = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].to_s
```

Basically, since this is for personal use (for my blog) only, all I want is a single user access at a time.

My question is besides the 'HTTP_USER_AGENT', how can one fake those pieces of information from my web app?  Is it possible to send a different IP address and session ID to Rails?  Just theoretically.  I'd like a glimpse of what's possible here...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that the browser sends can be forged from another browser to impersonate what your own browser is sending.

The only exception here is the remote IP address. That one is extracted from the connection by the web server and cannot be easily forged.

So using your authentication mechanism you might as well forget the session ID and user agent. Both are vulnerable to replay attacks.

So basically your method of protection then becomes IP address protection. That's fine for some simple personal pages, but if you store sensitive information on those pages you might want to think about using something more secure.

You can read the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) to get a better understanding of which attacks are possible and some basic security principles with Rails.